# Do you need to use the Firebase CLI locally for FCM push notifications to be seen in the browser?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I am developing a a React application that uses [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)  for browser notifications.

When developing/testing locally, do you need to be running your web application via the Firebase CLI tools (or something else Firebase-related) for push notifications to be visible via the browser? I know you must be running through HTTPS, but other than that I am unclear on requirements for local development and testing.

I know my browser is successfully connected to Firebase as I can successfully create FCM tokens in the browser.

I know the push notifications are being sent successfully via Postman since I see 200 OK responses such as the following:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 6313663323291515266,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "484e68e0-fc9a-4fb0-872d-870c9d9ac44c"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also see the following notification pop up, so I believe that my browser is getting the notifications, but not catching and displaying them correctly:

[screenshot - site updated in the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cnZ3.png)

When I test via [the FCM quickstart guide](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging) and `firebase serve -p 8081` I see browser notifications, but when I run my application over HTTPS and don't use `firebase serve`, I do not see any browser notifications.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "running through HTTPS"? Is the app being deployed to a hosting service? The "firebase serve" command will run an HTTP web server for testing, but as far as I know that shouldn't affect the Firebase SDK configuration or functionality.

Comment: I assumed that HTTPS was needed based on the docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client):
"The FCM SDK is supported only in pages served over HTTPS. This is due to its use of service workers, which are available only on HTTPS sites."

Based on that I would assume `firebase serve` runs an HTTPS web server (because otherwise how do I see notifications when running this)?